# the minimum hardware (RAM CPU) requirement of mono

Tags: mono

I search on

http://mono-project.com/FAQ%3a_Technical#Performance

but can not get information.

The size of download file at
http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html

are about 100M

but I hope to know the minimum hardware (RAM CPU) requirement of mono

Your comment welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this article  http://www.mono-project.com/Small_footprint it is possible to run mono on low spec hardware (32MB memory recommended). I'm running a webserver with Nginx/XSP/Mono3 on a `Raspberry Pi B` and can serve around 30 requests per second, so mono won't run fast on these kind of hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Mono has some performance (and exceptions when using GDI) issues with multiples threads in the Pi, I usually go back to "sequential/locking functions" when the .net app will run in mono. I recommend you building a small simple server to test the performance.